# Is there a way to detemine if the re-render is because of props or state change?

Tags: react-native, render

I want to stop the re-render on certain props changes, but if any state is changed i want it to re-render, I know one way is to check for all the states and props, but there's quite some complex data in the states, and i don't want to go through the computation of comparing them, cause i want to re-render on any state change, and only compare and stop the render when props are changed

Comment: What type of components you are using - class base or functional?

Comment: I'm using class based components majorly

Answer (score 1):

`shouldComponentUpdate` life cycle method do this what you want. Lets say this is our App component

```
import React from 'react';
import Counter from './Counter';
import './style.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      appValue: 0,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Counter
        appValue={this.state.appValue}
        updateHandler={() => {
          this.setState({ appValue: this.state.appValue + 1 });
          console.log('appValue update: ', this.state.appValue);
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

We use Counter component where we pass `appValue` and `updateHandler` as props. And in the Counter component, we render two values - Counter's own state value and appValue which is received as prop. Here is the Counter component:

```
import React from 'react';

class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      counterValue: 0,
    };
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.counterValue !== this.state.counterValue) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log('Inside render of Counter Component');
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <h1>Counter Value: {this.state.counterValue}</h1>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              this.setState({ counterValue: this.state.counterValue + 1 });
            }}
          >
            Update Counter Value
          </button>
        </div>

        <div>
          <h1>App Value: {this.props.appValue}</h1>
          <button onClick={this.props.updateHandler}>Update App Value</button>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

As you notice, when we click the `Update App Value` button - appValue will increase but won't show the updated value, that means Counter component won't re-render because of prop changing.

And when we click the `Update Counter Value` button - counterValue will increase and Counter component will re-render as-usual. We will see the updated appValue also.

This will happen because of condition checking inside `shouldComponentUpdate` life cycle method. To understand more clearly, notice the console.

**Here is a little bit about `shouldComponentUpdate` life cycle method:**

The `shouldComponentUpdate` is a lifecycle method in React. This method makes the component to re-render only when there is a change in state or props of a component and that change will affect the output.

The `shouldComponentUpdate()` is invoked before rendering an already mounted component when new props or states are being received.

Syntax:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time out robin, I already know the functioning of shouldComponentUpdate, what I want is before doing any comparison computation, I want to know if the render cycle is being triggered cause of a state change or a prop change.